# Adobe Acrobat DC Pro will not work / open for more than a short time, runs in background

Tags: pdf, windows-11, adobe-acrobat

Back in May 2022 I was having problems with Acrobat (Unable to "Save As PDF" or convert Word files to PDF and Cannot open PDFs from Explorer). I solved these by not just uninstalling but scrubbing Acrobat and Word from my computer.

Now I'm having all sorts of weird problems with Acrobat. I've tried checking for updates (none) and repairing (no change). I've tried uninstalling and scrubbing (Adobe Cleaner Tool), and reinstalling from various sources. It will work for a little while, then stop opening files from Explorer, then crash and refuse to open (but it will run, sometimes many instances, in background).

Trying to open PDFs sometimes brings up the "Something went wrong - A running instance of Acrobat has caused an error".

Here are the stats I assume are useful, but please let me know if other information is needed:

Acrobat DC, Version: 22.1.20191.0
Acrobat System Report says: OS Microsoft Windows 10, OS Version: 10.0.22000
System says: Windows 11 Home, version 21H2, build 22000.832, Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.832.0
Is that last discrepancy the problem?

Edit:
Windows updated, and I could use Acrobat for a whole day before it started acting erratically again. Current info/Acrobat System Report:

> Account Detail:
> User Rights: Admin
> User Account Control: Full
> Process Integrity: High
> Profile Type: None
> Acrobat Detail:
> Sandboxing: Off
> Protected View: Off
> Captive Reader: No
> Multi-Reader on Desktop Support: Off
> Applications Installed:
> Office Version: Office 2016 64-bit
> Outlook Version: Outlook 2016 64-bit
> Available Physical Memory: 4319228 KB
> Available Virtual Memory: 135286274528 KB
> BIOS Version: *ASUS* - 1072009
> Default Browser: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
> Version: 11.00.22000.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
> Creation Date: 2022/02/07
> Creation Time: 6:49:22 AM
> Default Mail: Microsoft Outlook
> mapi32.dll
> Version: 1.0.2536.0 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
>
> Display Detail:
> Screen Width: 1920
> Screen Height: 1080
> Number of Monitors: 2
> Number of Mouse Buttons: 8
> Has Mouse Wheel: Yes
> Has Pen Windows: No
> Double Byte Character Set: No
> Has Input Method Editor: Yes
> Inside Screen Reader: No
> Graphics Card: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620
> Version: 27.20.100.8682
> Check: Not Supported
> Installed Acrobat: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe
> Version: 22.2.20191.0
> Creation Date: 2022/08/02
> Creation Time: 5:32:04 PM
> Locale: English (Canada)
> Monitor:
> Name: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620
> Resolution: 1920 x 1080 x 59
> Bits per pixel: 32
> OS Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation
> OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10
> OS Version: 10.0.22000
> Page File Space: 39100712 KB Processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 10
> GenuineIntel  ~1800  Mhz Session Detail:     Boot Type: Normal    Is
> Shutting Down: No    Network: Available    Inside Citrix: No    Inside
> VMWare: No    Remote Session: No    Remote Control: No    Using JAWS:
> No    Using ZoomText: No    Using Windows-Eyes: No    Using NVDA: No
> System Name: LAPTOP-SLQF0845 Temporary Directory:
> C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Temp\ Time Zone: Eastern Standard Time
> Total Physical Memory: 16661284 KB Total Virtual Memory: 137438953344
> KB User Name: sarah Windows Detail:     Tablet PC: No    Starter
> Edition: No    Media Center Edition: No    Slow Machine: No Windows
> Directory: C:\WINDOWS

Comment: There happens to be an [update to 22.002.20191](https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/acrobat/apsb22-39.html) available, but quickly looking through the release notes didn't suggest to me that that is a known/fixed issue.